# how to send intent data between two activities using MVVM

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-mvvm

I want to send data from activity to another activity using MVVM but did't know what's the best way to get it in the receiver activity , is it right to use it like that, I see it totaly like mvc

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        ArrayList<Partner> partners = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("partners");

    }
```

Comment: i think that you should receive data in activity and pass the received data to the viewmodel

Comment: Getting data from the intent needs to happen in the Activity, even with MVVM.  Just create live data in the ViewModel of type `List<Partner>`, and set the live data from the activity, as well as observe it.

Comment: ok thanks too much